# How to center text for one of the column

Tags: html, css

I know this is funny but I have never heard the best way to center specific column inside table with tags col

I have table

```
<table>
<colgroup>
    <col />
    <col style="text-align: center;" />
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
       I must be in center
    </td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

But it doesn't center my text, I wonder why?

Comment: css: text-align:center;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in a perfect world, your solution would work, the CSS cascade doesn't quite work that way. But feat not, because CSS selectors are powerful. As I see it, your best option is to use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) or [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-of-type).

Or, you could add a classname to your cells (either manually or preferably programmatically), but that's just taking the easy way out ;-)

Further reading:

- [Can I use CSS3 Selectors](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)
- [How `:nth-child` works](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/).

Update:

Apparently, though, it is possible to apply styles to the actual `colgroup`: http://jsfiddle.net/aRYqx/.

Comment: You will want to note and test this with IE.  From the page link that is provided this is not supported with IE and you may run into problems.

Comment: @Sergey I experimented a little bit further, see the edit on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<colgroup>
    <col />
    <col style="text-align: center;" />
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
       I must be in center
    </td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
.center{
 text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cty4q/

Comment: I know this approach but if I have 1000 cells it means that class="center" will be rendered 1000 times, I don't want it that's why I asked this question, though maybe it will be only 1 solution...

Comment: This is the current method that is accepted to do this.  If you have 1,000 cells you should not be hand coding this webpage.  You should have a script to do that for you, and in that case your script should detect if it is a cell you want centered and then add this tag to it.

Comment: of course it will be doing by server code but html will increase the size. it means that for 1000 cells we will have 14000 characters more just for centering 1 column

Comment: servers can compress the http-body these days

Comment: And you also have to think of cross-browser compatibility.  The Nth element solution is not IE compliant, and there are many users out there that use IE.  So you will have a give and take issue on your hand as you decide which method to follow.